# wordpress plugin development - enqueue scripts

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am currently developing a WordPress plugin. I enqueue the following and also register them:

```
    wp_register_script('woo_checkout_tooltips_jquery_js', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');

    wp_register_script('woo_bootstrap_js', 'http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js');

    wp_register_style('woo_checkout_tooltips_css', plugins_url('css/bootstrap.css', __FILE__) );

    wp_register_style('woo_bootstrap_css', plugins_url('css/style.css', __FILE__) );

    wp_enqueue_style('woo_bootstrap_css');

    wp_enqueue_style('woo_checkout_tooltips_css');

    wp_enqueue_script('woo_checkout_tooltips_jquery_js');

    wp_enqueue_script('woo_bootstrap_js');

    wp_register_script('tooltip_options',plugins_url('js/tooltip_options.js', __FILE__),array(),NULL,true);

    wp_enqueue_script('tooltip_options');
```

Ony one of my development sites this works fine. When i come to install it on others i get the following error in the console of firebug:

```
TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
```

Does anything seem out of place above?

Answer (score 1):

Do not replace the bundled jQuery shipped with WordPress, [currently in version 1.8.3](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js). The core version is loaded in `noConflict` mode, and Google CDN version is not. Probably, there's something wrong with the dev setup where this code *is working*.

Apart from this issue, maybe you could add jQuery as dependency for `tooltip_options`:

```
wp_register_script(
    'tooltip_options',
    plugins_url('js/tooltip_options.js', __FILE__),
    array('jquery'), // <--- Dependencies
    NULL,
    true
);
```

Relevant Q&A's at WordPress Answers:

- [Including jQuery and jQuery files the correct way](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/45437/12615)
- [Wp theme Jquery conflict with plugins that use jquery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/30730/12615)
- [WordPress and jQuery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91598/12615)